# Failed to convert json array into List in powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-sentinel

I'm trying to retrieve tactics attribute from data.json and trying to create an array by using foreach loop. Ideally I'm expecting the array(TacticObject) in this format :[InitialAccess,PrivilegeEscation]

And this TacticObject will be sent as a parameter to New-Az
Sentinel Rule command for sentinel alert creation.

But the actual output is in the different format as mentioned below. Due to which unable to create a sentinel alert.

**data.json:**

```
{
     "displayName": "travel with mailbox permission",
     "tactics": [
            "InitialAccess",
            "PrivilegeEscalation"
          ],
          "techniques": [
            "T1078",
            "T1548"
          ]
  }
```

**code:**

```
  $content = Get-Content -Raw -Path "data.json" | ConvertFrom-Json
  [System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]]$TacticObject = @()
    foreach ($Tactic in $content.tactics) {
            $TacticObject.Add($Tactic)
         }  
    echo   $TacticObject
    
    New-AzSentinelAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspaceName -Tactic $TacticObject
```

**Output:**

```
InitialAccess
PrivilegeEscalation
```

**Error:**

```
[BadRequest] : Field 'tactics[0]' contains an invalid value 'InitialAccess PrivilegeEscalation'.
```

**Reference:**

```
https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/blob/master/Tools/Az.SecurityInsights-Samples/Alert%20Rules/Import%20Analytics%20Rules/importAzureSentinelRules.ps1
```

Comment: `-Tactic` expects a string not a list or an array hence the error you're seeing. You would need to enumerate your tactics and call the cmdlet per each

Comment: Can you please provide the sample snippet ?

Comment: Just putting the call inside that loop would suffice, change `$TacticObject.Add($Tactic)` to `New-AzSentinelAlertRule -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -WorkspaceName $workspaceName -Tactic $tactic`

Comment: Ideally one sentinel alert contain multiple tactics. That list I need to consolidate and provide to New-AzSentinelAlertRule command

Comment: If I use New-AzSentinelAlertRule  command inside for loop.. three times alert will be created for 3 different tactics.. that is not what I'm expecting

Comment: Have added reference in the above post